# Querying Google AppEngine's Datastore using PHP (through Quercus) and low-level API isn't working

Tags: google-app-engine

When I query Google AppEngine's datastore using PHP(through Quercus) and the low-level data-access API for an entity, I get an error that the entity doesn't exist, even though I've put it in the datastore previously.

The specific error is **"com.caucho.quercus.QuercusException:  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService.get:    No entity was found matching the key: Test(value1)"**

Here's the relevant code -

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory; 
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;

$testkey = KeyFactory::createKey("Test", "value1");
$ent = new Entity($testkey);
$ent->setProperty("field1", "value2");
$ent->setProperty("field2", "value3");
$dataService = DatastoreServiceFactory::getDatastoreService();
$dataService->put($ent);
echo "Data entered";

try
{
$ent = $dataService->get($testkey);
echo "Data queried - the results are \n";
echo "Field1 has value ".$ent->getProperty("field1")."\n";
echo "Field2 has value ".$ent->getProperty("field2")."\n";
}
catch(EntityNotFoundException $e)
{ 
echo("<br/>Entity test not found.");
echo("<br/>Stack Trace is:\n");
echo($e);

}
```

And here's the detailed stack-trace - [link](http://pastebin.com/Cr30sR7k).

This same code runs fine in Java (of course after changing the syntax). I wonder what's wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't told us what happens when you run the code. If it causes an exception, you need to include the stacktrace, too.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the stacktrace - [link](http://pastebin.com/Cr30sR7k).

Comment: I am puzzled by how it says that no entity matching the key Test(value1) was found, when I've put it into the datastore.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the stacktrace to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. It was caused by missing dependencies and I solved it by using the prepackaged PHP Wordpress application available [here](http://wordpress-on-quercus.appspot.com/wordpress-on-gae-quercus.zip).

One thing is to be noted. The package overlooked a minor issue in that all files other than the src/ directory need to be in a war/ directory which stays alongside the src/ directory (this as per appengine conventions as mentioned on its documentation). So I organized the files thus myself, put the above PHP file in the war/ directory, and it's working fine on the appengine.